# glmTMB, problem to model and graph a predictor

Tags: glmmtmb

I have used the glmmTMB package (beta function) to fit a model with several fixed effects, where I seek to predict an index of social stability in foraging groups (social rodents), based on socioecological predictors.

My question is the following: one of these predictors represents green grass cover (quality food), which has continuous data between 1 and 0 for the winter season, while it has only zero values for spring (period of extreme drought). I have run the model, with all the predictors. For quality food, the Estimate indicates a somewhat high slope and positive effect, but the graph has a line that is almost flat (perhaps since the model considers zeros for the graph). In the summary (output), I can see that all data (winter and spring) have been used. In this model I have not considered the food*Season as interaction, due to model non-convergence. So, here I think that I should model seasons and food as additive predictors, leaving winter as the reference term for the global model (intercept). Then, I must point out in the interpretation of the results that the effect size corresponds only to winter; since spring has no values, and in addition, I must plot winter (positive slope) and spring (no line, only zero data) in separate panels. Please, I would appreciate it if you can confirm if I am correct. Also, I appreciate any suggestions.

I ran all the data together, but I got an estimate that did not agree with the graph.